# QGIS Project Files Keeps Opening with 'Handle Unavailable Layers'

Tags: qgis

I'm quite new to QGIS so I suppose that this is likely an error on my part, but my project crashed and now whenever I open it I get the 'Handle Unavailable Layers' window pop up. I have never changed the location of my .shp files and so I press 'Auto-Find' or manually locate the .shp file in my directory and then click 'Apply Changes'. When the workspace is loaded, none of my assets actually show up, nor when I start a new project and drag a .shp file into it does it appear. Most of my assets were using .svg files which I personally imported but even normal .shp files with the default tools in QGIS are not appearing either. I cannot zoom to location or edit the layer in anyway to make it show up.

I managed to export it before it crashes so I still at least have an image of it, but I would like to prevent this from happening again. Here is what it looks like after I have loaded up the project file.

I am currently running 3.22.2 on Windows 10.

[image]

Comment: Do you have at least the 2 filename extensions .shx  and .dbf  with your shapefile in your folder ?

Comment: I only seem to have .shp, .dbf and .prj files, but if it means anything some files are defaulted to AutoCAD Shape Source and AutoCAD Compiled Shape. Do you suppose that there might a conflict in these which is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Your shapefile is probably corrupted since it's missing its .shx file !

https://docs.fileformat.com/gis/shx/